# Error message when trying to pool multiple imputations

Tags: r, statistics, imputation

I have completed a MI with mice in R and have followed the steps for pooling the results that I found on RDocumentation. I think I understand why I have completed the linear regression and now I am trying to pool the results but I keep getting an error message that says :

```
No tidy method for objects of class qr
```

I have tried installing tidyverse, broom, broom.mixed but none of these make the error message go away...

I am wondering if I have made it more difficult for myself by computing total scores after the imputation, but this is what I need for the lm...
Attaching my code here in case there is something really obvious that I have missed...

```
#Imputing data 
imp <- mice(df_2,  m = 5, seed = 2023)

df_imp <- complete(imp, "long", include = FALSE)

df_3 <- df_imp %>% mutate(
  DASS_stress = DASS_1 + DASS_6 + DASS_8 + DASS_11 + DASS_12 + DASS_14 + DASS_18,
  DASS_anxiety = DASS_2 + DASS_4 + DASS_7 + DASS_9 + DASS_15 + DASS_19 + DASS_20,
  DASS_depression = DASS_3 + DASS_5 + DASS_10 + DASS_13 + DASS_16 + DASS_17 + DASS_21,
  DASS_total = DASS_stress + DASS_anxiety + DASS_depression,
  IBQ_surgency = sum(IBQ_1 + IBQ_2+ IBQ_7 + IBQ_8, IBQ_13 + IBQ_14 + IBQ_15 + IBQ_20 + IBQ_21 + IBQ_26 + IBQ_27 + IBQ_36 + IBQ_37),
  COPE_approach_Eis = COPE_2 + COPE_7 + COPE_5 + COPE_15 + COPE_10 + COPE_23 + COPE_12 + COPE_17 + COPE_14 + COPE_25 + COPE_20 + COPE_24,
  COPE_avoidant_Eis = COPE_1 + COPE_19 + COPE_3 + COPE_8 + COPE_4 + COPE_11 + COPE_5 + COPE_15 + COPE_6 + COPE_16 + COPE_9 + COPE_21 + COPE_13 + COPE_26,
  COPE_total = COPE_1 + COPE_2 + COPE_3 + COPE_4 + COPE_5 + COPE_6 + COPE_7 + COPE_8 + COPE_9 + COPE_10 + COPE_11 + COPE_12 + COPE_13 + COPE_14 + COPE_15 + COPE_16 + COPE_17 + COPE_18 + COPE_19 + COPE_20 + COPE_21 + COPE_22 + COPE_23 + COPE_24 + COPE_25 + COPE_26 + COPE_27 + COPE_28,
  ISEL_appraisal = ISEL_2 + ISEL_4 + ISEL_6 + ISEL_11,
  TIPS_total = TIPS_1 + TIPS_2 + TIPS_3 + TIPS_4 + TIPS_5 + TIPS_6 + TIPS_7 + TIPS_8 + TIPS_9 + TIPS_10 + TIPS_11 + TIPS_12 + TIPS_13 + TIPS_14
)

fit_imp <- with(df_3, exp = lm(DS_score ~ DASS_total + IBQ_surgency + COPE_total + ISEL_appraisal + TIPS_total))

##summary(pool(fit_imp))

##pool_imp <- pool(fit_imp)
```

I have tried to pool with both of those hashtag/commented codes but both of them result in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the [`mice` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mice/mice.pdf), this is not how you obtain multiply imputed inference at all. You should not "complete" the data. The `mice` result has a special class, and some regressions (`lm`, `glm` for instance) has signed methods to handle the class - it fits models for each imputation and the *output* has a special class. You can then get the Rubin's Rules inference for those regressions using `pool` directly on that output.

The missing value should be regarded as a random value. "Complete" exists for two reasons, for one: to look at the result for sensitivity analyses - be aware `action=` has vastly different impacts on the result, and the default is long (it would be nice if Stef updated the default from `1L`). The second is to do by-hand regressions and application of Rubin's Rules in case the defaults aren't already added to `mice` (such as GEEs, maximum likelihood, etc.)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But if I get rid of the complete() then I am not able to mutate the variables to get total scores. Is it then possible to do the `lm` with survey items to then pool the results? Does that even make sense?

Comment: Couple schools of thought on this point - if you want to impute the items to get the total scores, then you need fit the imputed model over *each* imputed dataset, then combine errors by-hand with Rubin's rules. On the other hand, it doesn't always make sense to impute missing survey items because there is so, so often informative missingness. Most established scales have specific instructions for nonresponse.

Comment: @Lisa alternately, you can calculate the sum score in the unimputed dataset - with the score set to missing when the contributing items are missing - and then perform imputation. There is technical weeble-wobble doing this, but it gets close to the right answer.